# How do Christians who believe that Jesus preached to the dead in Sheol justify reversing the chronological order of verses 18 & 19 of 1 Peter 3?

Tags: exegesis, resurrection-of-jesus, chronology, 1-peter, place-of-the-dead

1 Peter 3:18-19 has been one of the most controversial passages in the Bible throughout time. And for good reason. I'd like to address a particular interpretation of the passage, however.

> 1 Peter 3:18-19 For Christ also suffered once for sins, the righteous for the unrighteous, that he might bring us to God, being put to death in the flesh but made alive in the spirit, in which he went and proclaimed to the spirits in prison,

You can see the interpretation in this answer [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/when-was-jesus-made-alive-in-the-spirit-1-peter-318/74394#74394).

Essentially, it says that "made alive in the spirit" is a reference to Jesus' resurrection, and "proclaimed to the spirits in prison" is a reference to Jesus preaching the gospel to the spirits of the dead imprisoned in Hades/Sheol *while* He was dead. Now, it's already a major assertion to say that "spirits" refers to *spirits of the dead*, and to say that "proclaiming" refers to *preaching the gospel*, and to say that "prison" refers to *prison in Hades[place of the dead]*, especially since nowhere in the entire passage are the spirits of the dead OR Hades mentioned. But we'll save that for another day. My question is... Why did the proclamation Jesus made take place during His death and not after His resurrection, i.e. what justification is there for such an interpretation? Peter places the event AFTER the event of Jesus being resurrected in his writing, so why isn't it that the event actually took place AFTER Jesus was resurrected(instead of BEFORE Jesus was resurrected)? Here's what I mean.

> 1 Peter 3:18-19 For Christ also **suffered once for sins[event 1]**, the righteous for the unrighteous, that he might bring us to God, being **put to death in the flesh[event 2]** but **made alive in the spirit[event 3]**, in which he went and **proclaimed to the spirits in prison[event 4]**,

Events 1, 2, and 3 are all in chronological order; each precedes the following with regards to the historical timing of the events. Jesus (1) suffered for our sins, (2) was put to death, and (3) was resurrected, in that order. Does Peter, in the middle of his sentence, break chronological order? Does event 4 precede event 3 chronologically, despite being placed AFTER event 3 in a sequence of chronological events? If event 4(Jesus proclaiming to the spirits in prison) happened *while* Jesus was dead, wouldn't Peter have said, "*being put to death in the flesh, in which he went and proclaimed to the spirits in prison, then made alive in the spirit*"? That way the event of Jesus proclaiming to the spirits in prison is shown to be chronologically prior to the event of Jesus being resurrected.

And if Peter was incapable of putting "*proclaimed to the spirits in prison*" in-between "*put to death in the flesh*" and "*made alive in the spirit*" due to such an act breaking the poetic parallelism(the poetic parallelism of "*put to death in the flesh but made alive in the spirit*"), why didn't he just clarify what he meant by saying, "*in which he went and proclaimed to the spirits in prison while dead*"? That would be a small price to pay for maintaining the poetic parallelism(presupposing, of course, that Peter not only intends to be poetic but that such poetry would come first and foremost over maintaining chronological consistency. Sure, Peter was most likely employing parallelism in verse 18, but was he required to do so? Does said parallelism take the primary slot? Is chronological consistency less significant than poetry?), and that way there would be no confusion(confusion due to him breaking the chronological sequence he had established) among of his readers.

So here are my questions for those that hold to the interpretation laid out in the [answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/74353/when-was-jesus-made-alive-in-the-spirit-1-peter-318/74394#74394) linked above;

- Why did Peter break the chronological sequence of events by placing "proclaimed to the spirits in prison" AFTER "made alive in the spirit", when Jesus proclaimed to the spirits in prison BEFORE He was resurrected, while He was dead(that is, according to the interpretation that asserts that)?
- What justification is there for saying that Jesus preached to the spirits in prison while He was dead despite the fact that Peter puts it after the event of Jesus being resurrected in a sequence of chronological events?
- Why is an interpretation that says that Jesus proclaimed to the spirits in prison while He was dead(before He was resurrected, thus breaking the chronological sequence Peter was laying out[since Peter placed the event of Jesus proclaiming to the spirits after the event of Jesus being made alive in the spirit in a chain of chronological events]) BETTER than an interpretation that says that Jesus proclaimed to the spirits in prison while He was alive(after He was resurrected, thus maintaining the chronological sequence Peter was laying out)?

Comment: In the same chapter Peter also puts the flood after the resurrection...I don't think he's trying to keep the chapter in strict chronological sequence, but he's giving definite flashbacks

Comment: "*I don't think he's trying to keep the chapter in strict chronological sequence*" Well I didn't say the chapter, but I was talking about the immediate context of v 19. "*but he's giving definite flashbacks*" Yes, but the flood happened 2400 years before Peter was writing; he would have had to break chronological sequence for that(there was nowhere else to put it). Did he have to break chronological sequence for "proclaim to the spirits in prison"? Not at all. As I said, all he had to do was place it in between "*put to death in the flesh*" and "*made alive in the spirit*". So why didn't he?

Comment: *why didn't he*? It would have broken the poetry of the parallelism in verse 18

Comment: Was Peter writing poetry though? That's clearly debatable. Even if he was writing poetry, and was forced to not put it(*proclaimed to the spirits in prison*) in between, why didn't he clarify that Jesus "proclaimed to the spirits in prison" *while* He was dead? Small price to pay for maintaining the poetry. How would Peter's readers know that he breaks the sequence of chronological events simply for the sake of poetic parallelism? And why would they think *that* instead of just thinking that "proclaimed to the spirits" happened chronologically after its antecedent("made alive in the spirit").

Comment: I reviewed the triple metaphor (and its relevance to Hades to a Hellenistic audience) in the linked post. I believe his readers did understand the metaphor--the early Greek Fathers understood it the way I've described. I recognize, of course, that you believe they were mistaken. I appreciate your not down-voting because you come to a different conclusion.

Comment: Perhaps it is a triple metaphor. However, Peter really wanted to emphasize a triple metaphor, wouldn't he have included water somewhere in "proclaimed to the spirits in prison"? There's obviously a connection between verses 20 and 21; both baptism and Noah's ark deal with water and how it corresponds to salvation(Noah was saved by the ark through the water, and we are saved by baptism in which we go through water), but neither water nor salvation(nor even Hades) is referred to in verse 19. You might be seeing a connection where there simply isn't one(don't worry, it's human nature :D).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't ask about the teachings of established Christian groups. Every individual's interpretation of the Bible is not on-topic here. Further questions can be directed to the person who originally gave that interpretation.

Comment: @curiousdannii Oh, I see. I didn't know every question has to be directed to a specific Christian denomination in order for it to not be closed. Well, thanks for explaining to me! Have a great day. :)

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no chronological issue. The idea that Jesus ’preached while dead’ is not biblically supported.

> but made alive in the spirit, in which he went and proclaimed to the spirits in prison

The key words are, “in which”. Being made alive ‘in the spirit’ is synonymous with his resurrection from the dead. He wasn’t made alive in the flesh, that’s how he died. He was made alive in the spirit- that’s when he spoke to the spirits - *after* his resurrection.

‘Spirits’ in the bible do not refer to humans, but to other of God’s creation. Post resurrection, Jesus said he wasn’t a spirit. Luke 24:39

Comment: "*No, there is no chronological issue.*" Yes, there wouldn't be under your interpretation(which I hold to). But not all share your interpretation. For others, there IS a chronological issue(see the answer linked in my question). That's why I'm wondering what they do with said chronological issue, and I'm also wondering why they hold to their interpretation(that leads to a chronological issue in the first place) rather than yours(which does NOT lead to a chronological issue).

Comment: Other interpretation requires deviation from plain speaking scripture. If we read what it says, there should be no contradiction.